# Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new to sharepoint 2013 and apps...

I just want to make sure I am doing this on the correct server(s). We have 4 serves (2 front-end, ca/application, and a database server).

0) "Configure the subscription Settings service application" - central admin/application server or the front-end servers?

1) For "You must configure a new name in Domain Name Services (DNS) to host the apps." this is configured for the central admin/application server right?

2) What domain should I base the app domain off of? For example, my corporate domain is mycorp.com, my sites are xyz.com and abc.com. Should I use mycorpapps.com for the app domain?

3) I have a model office (qa) environment and a production environment (4 servers each). Do I need to purchase 2 app domains, for example mycorpapps.com and mycorpappsdev.com.

4) Do I need SSL? My sites abs.com and xyz.com are using ssl. Currently the apps will not be referencing external data.

---

### moved to: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120680/server-clarifications-for-configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013

Thanks

Gina

Comment: Try asking this on the [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site instead; you're more likely to get a useful response there.

Comment: good call, I am always in the habit of using the general stackoverflow area.

Comment: moved to "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120680/server-clarifications-for-configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013"